# featherlight wordpress caption is being cut off

Tags: featherlight.js

Just installed featherlight for wordpress on our [website](http://www.abbeyroadfineart.com/artists/britt-hallowell/) and it works but the caption is cut off based on the image width. How do I change this so the entire caption is shown?

Comment: In order to get most out of StackOverflow, please be precise about your question and provide detailed information about what you've tried so far and how those attempts failed. See the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Either the CSS or the code of the plugin would need to be fixed (the caption bit is part of the plugin, not of the `featherlight` library itself).
I'd recommend [filing an issue](https://github.com/wpsitecare/wp-featherlight/issues)